# Implement natural dynamic Matrix in C++

Tags: c++, dynamic, operator-overloading, overriding

I actually have 2 questions about the same idea:

I want to create a TruthMatrix  class, How can i:

1. allocate a dynamic nXn matrix of bools, is the only way of doing it is as following?:

> class TruthMatrix {

```
        bool **mat;
    public:
        TruthMatrix(int n) {
            mat=new bool*[n];
            for (int i=0;i<n;i++) {
                mat[i]=new bool[n];
            }
        }
    };
```

1. override the [][] operator for quick access to the matrix elements such in mat[i][j]

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. No, it's not the only way. You could simulate a matrix with one large array, and you could use STL containers to ease memory management (for one). (Or use `dynamic_bitset` or similar).
2. It's probably not worth it. It's common for matrix classes to be subscripted with `operator()` because it's *much* easier to implement. To do it with several square brackets (akin to arrays of arrays) you need a suitable proxy object to return from your `operator[]` (do note that there's no such thing as `operator[][]`).

Example:

```
class TruthMatrix {
    /* ... */
    bool& operator()(int row, int column); // usage: matrixobj(1, 2)
};
// or
class TruthMatrix {
     /* ... */
     class Proxy {
         /* ... */
         bool& operator[](int column);
     };
     Proxy operator[](int row); // usage: matrixobj[1][2]
 };
```

Comment: can you make the assigment mat[i][j]=10 possible as well?

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is as follows:

```
vector<vector<bool>> tm(n, vector<bool>(n));

tm[i][j] = true;
```

Comment: thats nice, but im trying to learn how to implement such an idea myself rather then use a library...

Comment: you're aware that the library in this case is the standard C++ library.  ie vector is always available in every C++ toolchain.